# Web.Config Will Not Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config, msdeploy

Okay So I can't publish my web.config to my server.
I know why it's complete my fault.

When I signed up for hosting for a website the had documentation on how to not prevent posting your web.config so you wouldn't have to constantly change your connection string.

They had me go into an XML file and comment out some code. 
Maybe it might of been called MSDeploy or something.

I was wondering if anybody might know the file I am talking about and can point me to where it was so I can fix my mistake?

I know this may seem like a very specific question. However, it can help people figure out how to prevent publishing of a specific file in the rare case you need to do so. I know it can be useful atleast to some people so please don't close this question.

I'm also aware (now) that there are way better ways of publishing correctly, such as using transformations or a build script.

Also, the website removed the document on how to do this so I cannot work in reverse to fix it.

Comment: Are you saying that when you publish via Visual Studio, your Web.config file is not being deployed?

Comment: Yes when I publish via Visual Studio the web.config file will not deploy